# Will this hypothetical circular singularity FTL travel warp drive work?

Tags: black-holes, singularities, faster-than-light, wormholes, warp-drives

Not a physicist, but just wanted to know if this would work in theory:

Since nothing can practically travel faster than the speed of light (for now until proven otherwise), the only way for intergalactic space travel within an average human's lifetime is by creating a worm-hole.

Assume that humans are able to create and sustain a baby black hole singularity in space by some process, say a fusion-like reaction and feed it mass.

What if there are multiple such singularities arranged in a circular fashion, directed towards, say The Andromeda galaxy? Would they be able to propel a spacecraft through it ? Since the center of this effectively circular singularity would be pulled from all sides equally, the size of every black hole should be such that there is only a small area in the center where the event horizons don't overlap.

[image: Front view]

Like a warp-tunnel or warp-catapult, not exactly like a warp-drive that would continuously warp space, but a more static warp-catapult.

[image: Side view]

If this is possible, and if its possible to create and control singularities from the spacecraft, then the spacecraft might be able to keep creating warp-tunnels by generating these warp-catapults along the way. ( One problem though is finding enough mass along the way to feed the baby blackholes )

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not going to work because of the [topological censorship theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9305017). Basically it states that you cannot make configurations of spacetime (unless you have exotic matter) where there is a trajectory going through them that cannot be smoothly deformed into a trajectory going from the past to the future infinitely far away. In this sketch the spacecraft trajectory cannot be deformed into such a trajectory without crossing event horizons (where it will end at the black hole singularity instead).

When two black hole horizons overlap (or even get near each other) they merge. The result of this configuration is rather than a tunnel just a big, ellipsoidal black hole that rapidly rings down to a spherical black hole.